# Nested Multidimension Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Given this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [];
    var names = [{name : 'George'}, {name : 'Ringo'}, {name : 'Paul'}, {name : 'John'}];
    var surnames = [{surname : 'Harrison'}, {surname : 'Starr'}, {surname : 'McCartney'}, {surname : 'Lennon'}];

    for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            arr['firstname'] = names[i];
        for (j = 0; j < surnames.length; j++) {
            arr['firstname']['surname'] = surnames[j];
            arr['firstname']['surname']['index'] = i;
            console.log(arr);
        }
    }
</script>
```

When run, output in the inner loop would only show the last value of surnames array(Lennon) and i(3) on all entries. Output I want to achieve is for each name, surnames will be distributed to all firstnames (eg. John Harrison, John Starr, etc.) and index(i) will increment from 0 to 3. Thanks.

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: There are no associative arrays in javascript, thus you cannot store anything into `arr['firstname']` as it is.

Comment: @Dellirium, the OP can store data using his code: If you use a named index, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want Cartesian product of all first names with surnames.

try this

```js
 var arr = [];
 var names = [{
   name: 'George'
 }, {
   name: 'Ringo'
 }, {
   name: 'Paul'
 }, {
   name: 'John'
 }];
 var surnames = [{
   surname: 'Harrison'
 }, {
   surname: 'Starr'
 }, {
   surname: 'McCartney'
 }, {
   surname: 'Lennon'
 }];

 for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
 {
   for (j = 0; j < surnames.length; j++) 
   {
     var tmpObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(names[i]));
     tmpObj['surname'] = surnames[j].surname;
     tmpObj['index'] = i;
     arr.push(tmpObj);
   }
 }
 console.log(arr);
```

Alternatively you can also do

```
Object.create(names[i])
```

instead of

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(names[i]));
```

Comment: did you check your own code. Youre adding all combos of name and surname together.

Comment: @Craicerjack yes, that is what I though OP asked for.

Comment: @Craicerjack OP said `surnames will be distributed to all firstnames `

Comment: Exactly the output I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```js
var arr = [];
var names = [{
  name: 'George'
}, {
  name: 'Ringo'
}, {
  name: 'Paul'
}, {
  name: 'John'
}];
var surnames = [{
  surname: 'Harrison'
}, {
  surname: 'Starr'
}, {
  surname: 'McCartney'
}, {
  surname: 'Lennon'
}];

for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  arr.push({
      index: i,
      firstname: names[i].name,
      surname: surnames[i].surname
    });
  }
  console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this ,

```
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
       var obj = new Object;
        obj['name'] = names[i];
        obj['name']['surname'] = surnames[i].surname;
        obj['index'] = i;
        arr.push(obj);

}
   console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `arr['firstname']` is not an object to have a key!